# How to edit injected variable with remote host SSH on Jenkins?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I would like to edit my injected variables in my ssh built step,
then echo the results in my last execute shell built step.

From what i have seen so far, editing injected variable is possible with `Execute shell` built step, but `execute shell scripts on remote host using ssh` that's an other story.

For my injected variable i tried :

1. In `Build Environment` => `Inject environment variables to the build process`

```sh
var1=()
var2=()
var3=()
```

2. In `Build` => `Execute shell` :

```sh
touch env.properties
```

- `Injected environment variables`

Properties File Path : `env.properties`

Properties Content :

```sh
var1=()
var2=()
var3=()
```

And then finally, in my remote ssh built step i do a :

```sh
var1+=("1")
var2+=("2")
var3+=("3")
```

But nothing work ... (Final results : `var1=>(), var2=>(), var3=>()`)

Any idea to solve this ?